# Supporting sys.stdin.readlines() as well as command line arguments in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, stdin

I'm working on an application that can be launched directly, or via stdin.

Currently if I don't pipe any data to the application an EOF is never received and it hangs waiting for input (such as ctrl+d). That code looks like:

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    print("DEBUG: %s" % line) 
    if not line:
       break
```

I've also tried:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    print("DEBUG (stdin): %s" % line)
    return
```

However in both cases an EOF isn't received if the program is launched directly so it hangs waiting for it.

I've seen some unix applications pass a single `-` command line flag in cases where stdin input is expected but I'm wondering if there's a better workaround then this? I'd rather the user be able to use  the application interchangeably without remembering to add a `-` flag.

Comment: what does `via stdin` mean? Does that mean you launch it as a module?

Comment: @Sraw Stdin is the data coming from when you pipe into the application, for e.g. ```echo "a" | script.py``` puts 'a' as an element of sys.stdin

Comment: What's your system? I got the CTRL+D worked when calling the script directly without any pipe in a Linux.

Comment: @PhilipTzou I've used both bash/zsh - but the code is fairly straight forward (waiting for input that doesn't exist instead of continuing) and will fail in all circumstances. My intention is to not need the ctrl+D, but for stdin to work if passed, or cli arguments to work if passed.

Comment: *application that can be launched directly, or via stdin* Will you please illustrate the difference?

Comment: @Leon Stdin is often referred to as piping in information (see my post). The alternative would be calling it directly with command line arguments.

Comment: So why don't you just check for presence of command line arguments and use stdin only if no arguments were provided?

Comment: @Leon Because it needs to use both -  the STDIN is appended to flags if both are used. Plus that would be a hack, and prone to exceptions down the line.

Comment: What's wrong with the program waiting fro input? How would it be used when launched 'directly' rather than having data piped into it? Loads of UNIX tools just wait for input; try `cat` for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters To explain better - when nothing is piped in the application will then wait for sys.stdin indefinitely. This isn't the only way to use the application (as it's primarily driven by arguments) and thus it will completely stall. The use case is to have stdin as a supplement for data, not the direct driver.

Comment: Then being explicit is the better choice. Use an argument to pick the input (*read from filename, use `-` for stdin*).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Although I appreciate the input - not all contexts are the same. Both STDIN and arguments can be used in conjunction (wordlist building) and the environment this application is placed within is one where most applications will function in the manner I'm trying to here.

Comment: Using an argument to specify an input doesn't exclude using other arguments, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do is to check whether standard input is a TTY, and, if so, not read it:

```
$ cat test.py 
import sys

for a in sys.argv[1:]:
    print("Command line arg:", a)

if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print("stdin:", line, end="")

$ python3 test.py a b c
Command line arg: a
Command line arg: b
Command line arg: c

$ { echo 1; echo 2; } | python3 test.py a b c
Command line arg: a
Command line arg: b
Command line arg: c
stdin: 1
stdin: 2

$ python3 test.py a b c < test.py 
Command line arg: a
Command line arg: b
Command line arg: c
stdin: import os, sys
stdin: 
stdin: for a in sys.argv[1:]:
stdin:     print("Command line arg:", a)
stdin: 
stdin: if not sys.stdin.isatty():
stdin:     for line in sys.stdin:
stdin:         print("stdin:", line, end="")
```

Comment: Looks like this is the ticket - doing testing now and it's fairly robust. Any limitations that you are aware of?